# Method thinks it's a constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm following the "Math for Game Developers" YouTube series. The code worked without problems until I defined a Length() method inside the Vector class like so:

```
class Vector
    {
        public const float Length()
        {
            float length;

            length = Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y);

            return length;
        }

        public float x, y;
    }
```

Can one of you find what I've done wrong. The rest of the code has been left out because it isn't relevant, as far as i can see.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean it "thinks it's a constructor"?

Comment: That doesn't look like it should be defined as a `const`

Comment: and the next error would be Can not convert double to float on `length = Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y);`

Comment: Did you mean to tag this post as C#?

Comment: Those videos are done in C++ from what I just saw on YouTube. Why are you making it extra difficult to follow along by using a different language?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger He explicitly states that you can do it in whatever language you prefer.

Comment: Sure, that's absolutely true, but when you're trying to follow along with an instructional video or course, it's usually easier to stick to the language the instructor is writing code in.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger My reason to watch is the math, and underlying logic. Not learning to program.

Comment: You're watching a video series that introduces the viewer to how concepts of algebra apply to game development. If you're not looking to learn to program, then you may have come to the wrong place to get help, because most people here are going to expect you to have a working knowledge of the programming concepts you're working with. Please review the following page from the help documents http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants are identifiers that have a value that never changes. Because your function clearly uses variables to calculate the result, it cannot be constant.

Even if you had code like this though:

```
public const int ReturnNumber()
{
    return 5;
}
```

It would still break because in C#, you cannot have constant functions. You could do something like this though:

```
private const int Five = 5;

public int ReturnNumber()
{
    return Five;
}
```

So remember that the `const` keyword can only be applied to identifiers, not functions. Hopefully this explanation will help you understand.

Comment: No Problem! Hopefully the explanation made sense!

Answer (score 9):

There is no such thing as a `const` method in C#. Try removing that!

Answer (score 0):

"and the next error would be Can not convert double to float on length = Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y)"

Math.Sqrt returns a double. You can cast it to a float:

```
length = (float) Math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y);
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that right after fixing the issue in OP.